# parseDeftemplate in Jess application. Can't provide the JessTokenStream

Tags: parsing, jess

I'm implementing a methond in my application that uses the Jessp parser class in order to open a file and getting the deftemplates and deffacts inside of it. The problem is that when trying to obtain the result into a object variable, it asks on the constructor for a JessTokenStream. I tried to pass a JessToken, but then it complains about the type, that it should be e8. Searched through the Jess documentation but didn't found an explanation for the arguments, only the syntax of the constructor.
Anyone can help?.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you mean `jess.Jesp`? And the current Jess API does not contain a class `JessTokenStream`. - What's the code you have got so far? Which documentation were you searching, and the API/javadoc sure contains explanations of all parameters. Probably I should also ask for the Jess version.

Comment: @laune Well, the only reference i got in the documentation of the Jess apiis this:public Deftemplate parseDeftemplate(Context context,
                                    Rete engine,
                                    jess.JessTokenStream jts)
                             throws JessException

Comment: @laune I'm using the last jess version (71p2). Why is it that i can't use return for line feed when posting a reply here?. It goes straight to the save comment. that's the reason the previous post looks a bit weird. Will try to search through the site the way to insert code well indented in order to be readable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, strange. It's possible that here is the borderline of what you may access with a trial version. I can't call any Jesp method. Maybe ejfh will clarify this.

Comment: What is you intent for trying to parse files by calling Jesp? It's not something you'd normally want or need to do in order to run a Jess session.

Comment: The reason for that is that i need to identify deftemplates and deffacts from the supplied file and then separate them work with them on the application.

Answer (score 0):

The class JessTokenStream is not public, so you can't actually call those `parseXXX()` methods. They are public for historical reasons but aren't actually usable by clients. They should actually be removed from the public interface.

Instead, use the two-argument form of `parseExpression()`, and then test the returned object to determine its type. Then you can do what you want with the returned object:

```
Rete engine = ...
Jesp jesp = ...
Object o = jesp.parseExpression(engine.getGlobalContext(), false);
if (o instanceof Deffacts) {
    Deffacts d = (Deffacts) o;
    for (int i = 0; i<d.getNFacts(); ++i) {
        Fact f = d.getFact(i);
        Deftemplate t = f.getDeftemplate();
        System.out.println("Fact name is " + f.getName();
        System.out.println("Fact name is " + f.getName();
        for (String name: t.getSlotNames())
            System.out.println("Slot " + name + " contains " + f.getSlotValue(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used parseExpression() and it identifies correctly the deftemplate and deffacts part in the file but is there a way to get access to the content of the object?. The thing i was trying to do with parseDeftemplate was identify and grab the deftemplate in the file, and the same for the deffacts.

Comment: Deftemplate is a public class; cast the returned object to a Deftemplate and then use its API.

Comment: I have been trying to get it working using the returned object of parseExpression, but no result so far. It identifies correctly the type, but when trying to fetch the content of the object i can't.

Comment: I have been trying to get it working using the returned object of parseExpression, but no result so far. It identifies correctly the type, but when trying to fetch the content of the object i can't. The main purpose of what i want to do is, parting from a .clp file, obtain the different parts of a fact, i mean, fact name, slot names and values, and put them on a jtable. Then i want to take that data and use it elsewhere.

Comment: You can't, in what way? I'll add a little sample code to my answer above, and perhaps it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the code Ernst!. I finally understood what you tried to explain. Sorry for the late reply, i'm away from home and didn't have internet access available. From what i got from the code is that in the same way it is done with the deffacts, it is possible to do with the deftemplates, or another jess structure.